# How to execute two where conditions in laravel where order_id is same but product_ids are in array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I have a table ordered_products [ordered_products table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwIV6.jpg)

I have order id and multiple products_id now I want to fetch result based on orders_id and products_id
for example

```
orders_id =10 , products_ids = array(15,20,21,23)

$result = array();

 foreach (products_ids as $value) {
  $result=DB::table('ordered_products')->where('orders__id','=',10)->where('products_id','=',$value)->get();
  }
```

I executed the query, but I am only getting single row.
Please help me execute the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `where` for order_id and `whereIn` for product_ids

```
$result = DB::table('ordered_products')
            ->where('orders__id',10)
            ->whereIn('products_id', $products_ids)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you're running a query for each product, and overwriting $result each time. You can avoid the foreach loop and get all results by using `whereIn`.

```
$orders_id =10;
$products_ids = array(15,20,21,23)

$result=DB::table('ordered_products')
   ->where('orders__id','=',10)
   ->whereIn('products_id',$products_ids)
   ->get();
```

Comment: Thank You it worked. Unfortunately i can't mark both answer as correct but still thank you so much for your help.